# Does move semantics of C++11 reduce the need for manual memory management?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management

I was recently learning about rvalue refs and move semantics of C++11, and found out that they were really good for performance, as they avoid unnecessary copying. However, I can also see a positive side effect of move semantics, which is that it can reduce the need for manual memory management. To illustrate my point, let us take the following example.

```
std::string* getTheLongString()
{
    return new std::string("A really long string...");
}

std::string *a = getTheLongString();
........
delete a;
```

You could avoid call to delete, by using `unique_ptr`, but still that means that the programmer would have to take care of it. With `std::string` using move semantics, you could write the same example as follows, without loosing any performance.

```
std::string getTheLongString()
{
    return std::string("A realy long string...");
}

std::string a = getTheLongString();
```

So, what do you think. Does move semantics really make memory management easier in C++?

Comment: No, you would write it the second way even without move semantics. The first version is just asking for trouble.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think RVO was already implemented before move semantics were introduced, so it doesn't change anything in your second example.

Comment: Ah I see. Yes, I also read about the Return value optimization thing. So, in this case, the compiler could surely optimize that. But for some more complex code, maybe that wouldn't be possible.

Comment: If you really wanted to avoid a copy pre-C++11, you'd return a pointer as in the first case, but the caller would immediately stuff that into a smart pointer and not need to manually free it using the `delete[]` operator.

Comment: Yes, but that would require the programmer to carelly use smart pointers where necessary. With move semantics, even that is not needed. The less pointers, the better.

Comment: *"reduce the need for manual memory management."* smart pointer especially `std::unique_ptr`, thanks to move semantic, reduce manual memory management. its deprecated predecessor `std::auto_ptr` has several pitfalls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lack of Move Semantics pre-C++11 or the paranoia of Return Value Optimization pre-C++17 have never been a good reason to use "*dynamic storage duration*" in place of "*automatic storage duration*".

- Pre-C++11:

  Compilers were doing Return Value Optimization. If you were paranoid about RVO not happening, one of the ugly hacks was "out" parameters

  ```
  void getTheLongString(std::string& str){
      ....
      str = "A realy long string...";
  }

  std::string a;
  getTheLongString(a);
  ```

  "Initializing" `a` here requires "Two work". Default Construction and a Copy Assignment.
- C++11 and C++14:

  Compilers are still doing Return Value Optimization. You don't need to worry about it not happening, because worse case would be a Move Construction.

  ```
  std::string getTheLongString(){
      return std::string("A realy long string...");
  }

  std::string a{getTheLongString()};
  ```

  "Initializing" `a` here is at most one work.
- C++17 and beyond.

  Return Value Optimization (more formally "*Copy Elision*") is guranteed to take place in the particular definition of `getTheLongString()`. So nothing to worry about.